# How to get the types of a prisma model and place them in an array in Nestjs?

Tags: nestjs, prisma

I have a `Nestjs` app using `Prisma`. For one given model, I want to send via controller the model attributes with its types, so that I can generate a form in the front end. What is the best way to do it?

What I have:

A prisma model and its corresponding DTO class in Nestjs:

```
// create-job-offer.dto.ts
import { IsOptional, IsNumber } from 'class-validator';

export class CreateJobOfferDto {
  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  mentorId: number;

  @IsNumber()
  @IsOptional()
  companyId: number;
}
```

I want to be able to send to my FE something like:

```
[{key: 'mentorId', type: 'number'}, {key :'companyId', type: 'number'}]
```

So that I can create a form, and for every input have the correct type. For example, if type is boolean, I'd generate a checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScipt type is not an object. You can not treat typescript types as objects - ie can't iterate through them etc.
The standard way to share types is to use a @types package. TSLang website has a good explanation on how that works.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html

However, at my company, we will only use @types packages for packages that get published to npm because it takes too long to create one.

We will have a `types.ts` file for each module. Say, a `custom-form.types.ts` file, which may have the following code in it.

```
export interface MentorForm {
  mentorId: number;
  companyId: number | undefined;
  mentorName: string;
 ...
}
```

And then we will share this file with the frontend development team. Because of how typescript works, you can not iterate through the keys of the interface directly. You can use a transformer to get the keys of an interface in an array.

```
const KeysOfMentorForm = keys<MentorForm>();
```

If you want to generate your forms in the front end programmatically, the easiest option would probably be to do something like this.

```
let mentorA : MentorForm;
let keyAndTypeArray : {key : string, type: string}[] = [];
for(let key of KeysOfMentorForm){
    let type : string = (typeOf mentorA[key]).toString();
    keyAndTypeArray.push({key : key, type : type})
}
```

Then you can iterate through the `keyAndTypeArray` to generate the form.